# three.js : how to specify inside and outside material on each face

Tags: three.js

New in three.js, I would like to define several materials for a box geometry.

The idea is to make something like a a wood plank that has been painted on top and bottom (but not on the sides). Drilling the plank might induce seeing the internal material on the hole borders.

I though using THREE.MeshFaceMaterial but I do not know if it is the good way and how to do it as I need :
Material1 to be applied on Top and Bottom external only
Material2 to be applied on on all other faces (external and internal) and on top internal and bottom internal

Thank you for your help